# Replacing a word that matches with a Key is not working in Python

Tags: python

So I am trying to replace a word that matches any of the keys in the dictionary by its values.

Below is the current code I have and my code is not replacing anything.

```
       for k, v in fdict.items():
           if word == k:
               word == v
```

So basically in the end I want the following to happen.

Comment: Notice that `==` is returning a boolean value. If you want to change the value of a variable, you need to use `=`.

Comment: can you give me sample data in realtest.json?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ the following link contains 2 files. the first one is words in the dictionary and the second one is json file. Thank you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=15vN7AsXt6S6ATUmJYyUTjIHGa-cJ2dxR

Comment: @KhanShur please put any sample json in the question, rather than in links

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```py
for word in (jsondata['value']['segments'][i]['transcriptionData']['content']).split():
    word = fdict.get(word, word)
```

By using `get`, you are seeing if `word` is a valid key, if it is, return the associated value, otherwise, return the second argument as default, in this case `word`. You don't need to iterate through `fdict`, as that sort of defeats the purpose of the dictionary in the first place. Testing for membership is a time-constant process and fast.

If you want this to be reflected in the dictionary itself, you need to re-assign the value at that key:

```py
# changing this to be more pythonic and readable
for segment in jsondata['value']['segments']:
    # assigning this to be a different variable for readability
    words = segment['transcriptionData']['content'].split()
    # join will make this a string again so we can re-assign it
    # to the key
    words = ' '.join(fdict.get(word, word) for word in words)

    # Now this will be reflected in your json
    segment['transcriptionData']['content'] = words
```

Furthermore, in your `if` statement, `word==v` will return `False`, as `==` is an equality test, not value assignment, and that should have been `word = v`

To address the update in the question, you never write your updated `words` anywhere. The data in your program is *not* the file, so any modifications made to the data will not be reflected in the file until you write the data back to the file.

```py
# after you update words
# Note, this is a different file path, as w will truncate (wipe out) the 
# file if it exists, so use a different file path until you are sure your
# logic is sound
with open('somefile.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(jsondata)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It seems to be a good solution. But it's still not updating my original file. I am not sure what's going on. If you have time please check out this 2 files. https://drive.google.com/open?id=15vN7AsXt6S6ATUmJYyUTjIHGa-cJ2dxR

Comment: How would it update your file? It doesn't look like you are writing that json back to anything. Also, that was not mentioned in the question

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I have updated my question! I have tried doing the following but it did not update the file. jsondata['value']['segments'][i]['transcriptionData']['content'] = word